# How does addToBackStack() work?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, back-stack

I just dont get it.

I have an Activity `A`, and a Fragment `F1` and a Fragment `F2`.
When the activity starts, it opens `F1` by

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, new BookChoose())
            .addToBackStack(BookChoose.TAG)
            .commit();
```

Then in the new  fragment there is a button with an `onClickListener` registered which spawns `F2` by

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .add(android.R.id.content, new BookPlay())
             .addToBackStack(BookPlay.TAG)
             .commit();
```

Then when I press back, it throws me to homescreen. Should't the last transaction be reverted and I'd be at `F1`?

Comment: Replace your tags with `null` and see if that helps. Also, unless there is something else to Activity A than Fragment F1, you don't want to use `addToBackStack()` for F1, because then BACK removes the fragment and would leave you with an empty activity.

Comment: are `BookChoose.TAG` and `BookPlay.TAG` different?

Comment: The Tags are different. I now deleted the addToBackStack from my activity and only F1 calling F2 has a addToBackStack. I also overwrote onBackPressed() so it logs the size of backStack (which is now 1 after starting F2 and calls its super.onBackPressed() now.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Fragments docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions), what you should do is :

```
Fragment newFragment = new BookPlay ();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the content view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.content, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```